# How to a form a nice Table in TeX (not LaTeX)

Tags: plain-tex

I want some nicely formated tabular thing in TeX. What are my options.
Having no documentation unlike in TeX I am lost.

Comment: Maybe you'll find something [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181046/table-like-layout-in-plain-tex) or [here](http://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/halign.html).

Comment: “Nicely formatted” depends on the data. Can you please show an example of what you need to show?

Comment: If you are using TeX, I hope you at least have the TeXbook by Knuth.

Answer (score 8):

The question is a bit broad as asked, but I'll do my best to provide a reasonable answer. If you're doing anything sophisticated in TeX, I recommend you read Knuth's *The TeXbook*. The relevant text here is Chapter 22: Alignment, pages 235-249.

---

You're probably looking for `\halign`, which is a “tabular thing.” It stands for “horizontal alignment.” The example below creates a table showing the number of internet users in different countries (from www.internetworldstats.com).

```
\halign{\strut\hfil#\hfil\quad&\hfil#\hfil\quad&\hfil#\cr
   Rank&Country&Internet Users\cr
   \noalign{\hrule}
   1&China&1388232693\cr
   2&India&1342512706\cr
   3&United States&326474013\cr}
```

[image: Internet Users in Countries Code Product]

The structure of an `\halign` is similar to that of a `tabular` environment in LaTeX, which makes sense because the `tabular` environment is built on `\halign`. The first line of the `\halign` is called the *preamble* and defines templates for each cell. Data is entered by rows. Each cell is separated by `&`, and each row is ended by `\cr`. The data from each row is inserted into the template and aligned. The placeholder character in each template is `#`.

I won't go into too much more detail. Check out *The TeXbook* or the [link](http://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/halign.html) that Phelype mentioned in the comments. They're both good resources.

`\halign` is powerful but fairly bare bones. There are a number of plain TeX packages on CTAN that make things nearly as simple as `tabular`. Check out [`stables`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stables) (which I like) and [`tap`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tap) (which I haven't used). I'm pretty picky, so I usually roll my own solution.